# getting exception: null when I try to do a left join in Spring jpa;

Tags: spring, jpa

Query that with join which works

```
@Query(value="select new com.sarthak.split2.pojos.UserAmount(u.id,g.g_id,b.amount) from User u  join u.groups g join u.bills b ON b.user.id=u.id and b.group.g_id=g.g_id")
    public List<UserAmount> getlist2();
```

But when i add a left join instead of join, i get an exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null

```
 @Query(value="select new com.sarthak.split2.pojos.UserAmount(u.id,g.g_id,b.amount) from User u  join u.groups g left join u.bills b ON b.user.id=u.id and b.group.g_id=g.g_id")
        public List<UserAmount> getlist2();
```

Comment: You don't need ON when you defined the relationships in your entity. How does your entity look like?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by adding an case, the problem was it was returning a null type and the method accepted integer.

```
@Query(value="select new com.sarthak.split2.pojos.UserAmount(u.id,g.g_id,case when b.amount is null then 0 else b.amount end) from User u  join u.groups g left join u.bills b ON b.user.id=u.id and b.group.g_id=g.g_id")
        public List<UserAmount> getlist2();
```